# How to use API in idealista with python

Tags: python, api, web-scraping

is there a way to use idealista Api in python or a simpler way ?
I didn't try this before.
I have the APIkey and the secret, and have a list of cadastral codes, so want to get rent price for each code!

Comment: Please improve your question by posting appropriate URL or code if you have tried already

Answer (score 2):

Hi this works for me using Python 3.8

First you need to get the token from Idealista:

```
import json
import requests
import base64

def get_token():
    API_KEY= "YOUR_API_KEY"
    SECRET= "YOUR_SECRET"
    message = API_KEY + ":" + SECRET
    auth = "Basic " + base64.b64encode(message.encode("ascii")).decode("ascii")

    headers_dic = {"Authorization" : auth,
                   "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"}

    params_dic = {"grant_type" : "client_credentials",
                  "scope" : "read"}

    r = requests.post("https://api.idealista.com/oauth/token",
                      headers = headers_dic,
                      params = params_dic)

    bearer_token = json.loads(r.text)['access_token']

    return bearer_token
```

With that token now you can access the search api:

```
def get_search():
    headers_dic = {"Authorization" : "Bearer " + TOKEN,
                   "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

    params_dic = {"operation" : "rent",
                  "locationId" : "0-EU-ES-01",
                  "propertyType" : "homes"}

    r = requests.post("https://api.idealista.com/3.5/es/search",
                      headers = headers_dic,
                      params = params_dic)

    result_json = json.loads(r.text)

    return result_json
```

I found that the locationId goes from `0-EU-ES-01` to `0-EU-ES-56` for Spain. I didn't try the other countries.

Comment: Do you have any documentation of the possible params to include in the request?